# How to show shops that have at least 10 sells

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with shops(id, shopname ,address), and another table sales(shopsid, product, price, quantity). 
How could i display the shops that have at least 10 sales,

i know that this line of code is bad `where count(shopsid) >= 10`

```
select id, shopname from shops
join sales on sales.shopsid = shops.id
where count(shopsid) >= 10
order by id;
```

what i want to see is the id of the shops that have at least 10 sales. 
and i dont know how to make that count work, or to implement properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use group by when you use aggregate function

```
    Select Id,shopname
   from shops s join sales ss on ss.shopsid=s.id
   Grop by id , shopname
   Having count(*) between 10 and 15
```

Having is group filter so you have to use having instead where

Comment: What about a product that is sold in all shops?

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, shopname from shops
join sales on sales.shopsid = shops.id
GROUP BY id, shopname
HAVING count(shopsid) >= 10
order by id;
```

Comment: is it possible to have it between 10 and 15 for example?

Comment: Thanks mate. Much appreciated, i will tick as soon as it will be available.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the `id`s of the shops, you don't need a `join`:

```
select shopsid
from sales
group by shopsid
having count(*) >= 10;
```